# Is there any problem with these TSL201R IC's?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I ordered two TSL201R DIP-8 on a chinese website, which I thought should look like this :

[image]

However, I received these two guys :

[image]

As hobbyist I've never seen this kind of IC's before, so is it a kind of protective wrapper, or just a scam (or anything else) ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is there a data sheet available for the part you thought you ordered. If not then why did you order it?

Comment: and that, kids, is why you don't order from someone who you don't know and who has to stand zero repercussions if they don't deliver exactly the thing you've ordered.

Comment: (and to not just belligerently bicker:Your component isn't in production anymore,and it will be very expensive to get old stock. Here's [a list](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/specialized-sensors/561?FV=ffe00231%2C5640065%2C56400ae&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&pageSize=25) of potential alternatives that you can actually buy, and will actually get, from an actual reputable electronics distributor. Check https://octopart.com for alternative sourcing; mouser, arrow, digikey, rs comp, element14/farnell, avnet are the large reliable players in electronic components)

Comment: Actually, I bought it on chinese site indeed because I didn't found them anywhere... And I already bought chinese used chips without any problem, I know I play lottery doing this (I should have mention that in my question :) ) Anyway, @MarcusMüller thank you for your list of alternatives  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are not TSL201 ICs. Looking at [the datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/TSL201R-LF-TAOS-datasheet-8327114.pdf), the optical response is centred around 700 nm, it looks unlikely that case is transparent at that frequency. Additionally, the pin spacing looks odd - the spacing is not equal, which it would be for a DIP8 part. In the datasheet page 9, you can see it looks like the "real" picture you included. Try hooking them up functionally, but I think these are not the ICs you are looking for. Whether this is malicious, or an honest error is for you to work out with the seller (good luck!).

Comment: Considering that the TSL201 isn't available at any reputable distributor, and this isn't Rochester (or any other retailer that specializes in buying up "last buy/obsolete" stock): I doubt this was an oversight.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I hope the "(good luck!") hinted towards that..! ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! And by the way, have you ever seen this kind of chips ? Does they may be used for something else, for example modelling or tests ?

Comment: @RemyF looks like 1980s IC copies; so, leftover unmarked stock that someone threw away, maybe?

Comment: @RemyF You are welcome, sorry it was bad news! I've never used the TSL201s, and the things you have are unidentifable (no markings), so can't help you further on that front either.